# Cannot concat a XSL variable with a javascript String?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath, concatenation

So I'm trying to pass a XSL variable to a js function and then concat it with a string, but it does not work.

This is what I tried:

```
<msxsl:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="js"> 
<![CDATA[
  function printString1(str)
  {
     str2 = 'hello' + str;
     return str2;
  }
]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

And this is how I call the method:

```
<xsl:value-of select="js:printString1(s:somepath/@name)"/>
```

Where the name is "Jake".

In this case the output is "hello" and nothing else. Should it not be "helloJake"?

But if I try:

```
<msxsl:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="js"> 
<![CDATA[
  function printString1(str)
  {
     return str;
  }
]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

I get "Jake" as the output.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

This is how the XML file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MeasDataStylesheetWithScript2.xsl"?>

<measCollecFile 
xmlns="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/32_series/32.435#measCollec" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="measCollec">
    <fileHeader vendorName="samplename">
</fileHeader>
</measCollecFile>
```

And this is how the XSL file look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:s="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/32_series/32.435#measCollec"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"   
xmlns:js="urn:custom-javascript"
exclude-result-prefixes="s msxsl js">

<msxsl:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="js"> 
  <![CDATA[
      function printString1(str)
      {
         var str2 = 'hello' + str;
         return str2;
      }
  ]]>
</msxsl:script>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>

    <xsl:value-of select="js:printString1(s:measCollecFile/s:fileHeader/@vendorName)"/>

  </body>
  </html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set `var` to `str2`:

```
    <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="js">
        <![CDATA[
  function printString1(str)
  {
 var str2 = 'hello' + str;
 return str2;
  }
]]>
    </msxsl:script>
```

I tried following template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:js="js"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="js">
        <![CDATA[
  function printString1(str)
  {
 var str2 = 'hello' + str;
 return str2;
  }
]]>
    </msxsl:script>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="js:printString1('Jake')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output: `helloJake`

---

**EDIT**

Use XPath `string` function, e.g.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="js:printString1(string(s:measCollecFile/s:fileHeader/@vendorName))"/>
```

Comment: just tried and it does NOT work. do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I have included exactly how the source file will look. While you are correct that passing a string like 'jake' will work, extracting a string from the xml file will not.

Comment: Yes! Just being curious, what is being passed without the string() command? It can be returned as text but not manipulated...

Comment: @Simon,  As XSLT engine (in my case it is MSXML) says: `MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathArrayIterator`